SQLAlchemy ORM Declarative Model reference mapper problem
I have two simple models defined using SQLAlchemy ORM. In my models there is a many to one relationship between APIKey and Member. The models were created following the guide on the SQLAlchemy docs.
The models are as follows:
class Member(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'members'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), unique=True)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(120), unique=True)
    password_hash: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(128))
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    keys: Mapped[List["app.models.APIKey"]] = relationship(back_populates = 'api_member', cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Member %r>' % self.username
   
    # other functions

class APIKey(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'api_keys'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    api_key: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), unique=True)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    expires_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=30))
    is_active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=True)

    member_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('members.id'))
    api_member: Mapped["app.models.Member"] = relationship(back_populates = 'keys')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<APIKey %r>' % self.api_key

    # other functions

When I try to initialize the models using the ORM (eg. member = Member(**args)) I get the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: reverse_property 'api_member' on relationship Member.keys references relationship APIKey.api_member, which does not reference mapper Mapper[Member(members)]


I have tried to use other back reference syntax, tried switching to a different database and other small adjustments but the problem has persisted. The models are essentially copies of the guide so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I haven't received any error from your example here https://bpa.st/DPAQ. I'm guessing you are doing something else.
